# tcolorbox breaks the verbatim definition of ltugboat documentclass

Tags: verbatim, document-classes, tcolorbox

This code:

```
\documentclass{ltugboat} 
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document} 
    \begin{verbatim}[\small]
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tikzduck}
    \begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \duck
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
    \end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

produces this output:

[image]

whereas if you comment out `\usepackage{tcolorbox}`, the output is correct:

[image]

Comment: tcolorbox loads the verbatim package and this redefine verbatim. Probably it would be the best to ask @barbarabeeton how to handle this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `[\small]` is a feature of `ltugboat` `verbatim`. If you use a different `verbatim`, you have to get rid of it. At least, I can't picture a different solution, sorry.

Instead, you can use something like

```
{\small \begin{verbatim}
...
\end{verbatim}
}
```

But I would guess you already knew that.

Comment: I knew about that but it didn't come to my mind! Thank you!

Comment: It should be `{\par\small\begin{verbatim}`, otherwise `\small` will have effect on the paragraph before the verbatim material, unless a blank line is added in between.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know how much `tcolorbox` relies on `verbatim` as defined by the homonym package that it loads, so something like

```
\documentclass{ltugboat}

\let\ltverbatim\verbatim
\let\ltendverbatim\endverbatim

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\let\verbatim\ltverbatim
\let\endverbatim\ltendverbatim
```

may possibly yield problems when embedding verbatim material in `tcolorbox` environments.

A different approach is to use `fancyvrb` for your verbatim (non `tcolorbox`) material:

```
\documentclass{ltugboat}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[2]
\begin{Verbatim}[fontsize=\small]
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikzduck}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \duck
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
\end{Verbatim}
\lipsum[3-5]

\end{document}
```

(avoid indenting `verbatim`). You can also set `\small` size by default with `\fvset{fontsize=\small}` in the preamble.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, yours is a very good solution! However, I still prefer to use Karl Berry's one because he is the manager of `ltugboat` documentclass. I'll look at TUGboat to see which is the standard for indentation. Ciao :)